# Android: How to move camera to my location only on each time I first start my application?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I am developing an android app which includes Google maps api. Camera is moved to my current location whenever I start the activity. Even after going to some other activity on return it agains starts to point to my current location.  I want to move camera only on the first time when I start the application. I want not to move camera after returning from some other activity. How can it be implemented?

Currently, I declared a boolean var `shouldMove` on top and in the `onCreate` method, set its value to true. And after that `onLocationChanged` method, I put an if statement i.e. `if(shouldMove)` tk check the variable value. If it's true then move the camera otherwise not. So in case of true,  first move the camera and then I set its value to false. But whenever I switch to another activity and return back to `mapsActivity`, its value is again set tk true, which I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the variable 'shouldMove' not in the activity class. In some other static class (for example, Application). 
There, and change the value of the variable, then it will not depend on the Activity.

Example:

Create Application class:
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
      private boolean shouldMove;

```
  public boolean isShouldMove() {
     return this.shouldMove;
  }
}
```

in your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        MyApplication myApp=(MyApplication)this.getApplication();
        if(myApp.isShouldMove()) {
            ...
        }         
    }
}
```